# Understanding Chef only_if not_if

Tags: chef-infra

Im not sure I understand Chef conditional execution.

I'd like to do some conditional execution based on whether or not a database exists in Postgresql

So here's my example

```
execute "add_db" do
  cwd "/tmp"
  user "dbuser"
  command "createdb -T template_postgis mydb"
  not_if 'psql --list|grep mydb'
end
```

Running `psql --list|grep mydb` return what you would expect if the db exists (the line with the dbname entry) and nothing at all if it doesnt.

So how does not_if only evaluate that? True or false? 1 or 0? Dont all processes return 0 if they are successful?

Anywho any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just ran into this issue. My problem was that the not_if command was being run as 'root', not 'dbuser'. If you change it to

```
not_if 'psql --list|grep mydb', :user => 'dbuser'
```

then you may get the results you were looking for.

http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-438

Comment: My situation was a bit difference, so I will leave a note here for future users in a similar situation who landed here. Say you have an attribute `node['myattr'] = true`, then if you write `only_if node['myattr']`, chef will complain. I discovered that you need to enclose the statement in curly braces, ie. `only_if { node['myattr'] }`

Comment: Here's [the documentation for the `:user` argument for `not_if`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/#arguments)

Answer (score 21):

Run the test for yourself, from the command line, and take a look at the default return value (a.k.a., "$?").  You should get something like this:

```
    % psql --list|grep mydb
    mydb-is-here
    % echo $?
    0
```

If you try something that is not there, you should get something like this:

```
    % psql --list|grep mydb-not-here
    % echo $?
    1
```

What chef is going to be looking at is the numeric value that would get stuffed into $?, i.e., either a "0" or a "1".  In other words, your example you show for the "not_if" syntax is correct.

Comment: Like how you gave them an example of how to figure it out on there own!

Comment: I usually add a -q to the grep invocation when putting it in a recipe so the chef-client output does not get cluttered with any matches produced by grep.