# Chef execute resource not_if guard returns 1; still skips

Tags: chef-infra

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392973/understanding-chef-only-if-not-if), which is very similar, but I'm executing the test code on-instance, which, according to [the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/#guards), means the guard should not be applied. However, it's skipping each time. Any help would be appreciated.

The Chef code:

```
# Install the DNS plugin for the CLI
execute 'Install-DNS-plugin' do
  command 'akamai install dns --force'
  not_if 'akamai list | grep dns'
end
```

Always results in a skip:

```
==> default:   * execute[Install-DNS-plugin] action run
==> default:  (skipped due to not_if)
```

Even though, on the instance, the guard code returns 1:

```
[root@vagrant ~] $ akamai list | grep dns
[root@vagrant ~] $ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the akamai cli rely on a specific environment variable or shell initialization? Both may not be present from `not_if` unless you specify them. See https://docs.chef.io/resource_common/#arguments

I would suggest running the `akamai list | grep dns` in an execute resource itself to debug the result.